# use of libraries like bootstrap and semantic ui

Tags: web, bootstrap-4

Do you use bootstrap, semantic ui or any other library for building web pages, or do you directly code the html and css yourself?

I am curious whether developers use the frameworks or prefer the traditional way of doing things?
Please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always depends on what you want.
If It's about get the shit done very quickly and with a good Ui, use bootstrap or another libraries, but if you something very unique, you make your own styles.
But generally we use a combination of both, libraries and our own styles when is necessary.